# Как зашифровать String в андроид?

Tags: java, android, android-sdk

Добрый день. В коде имеется final String, содержание которой очень не хотелось бы, чтобы его узнали при декомпиляции. Как можно максимально эту задачу усложнить?

Comment: Как минимум, например, можно вместо строки хранить `byte[]`, который по какому-то алгоритму будет превращаться в нужную строку

Comment: использовать любой алгоритм шифрования

Comment: запрячьте стрингу в натив, зашифруйте например XOR-ом, и расшифровывайте. Храните массив байт

Comment: Или использовать String Bytcode Obfuscator